# Tensorflow valueError

Tags: python, tensorflow

I made a script and it seems work well.

But, sometimes it stuck with

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3480 into shape (1,60,60,1)

I don't know why it stuck.

The code is like this.

It makes some small window and capture the screen.

Sometimes it works very well without no problem.

But, sometimes on the other hand, it returns value Error

```
import sys, logging

logger = logging.getLogger("log")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
fh = logging.FileHandler("logging.log", encoding="utf-8")
logger.addHandler(fh)
try:
    from screen_processor import IMGScreenCapturer
    import cv2, time, os
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow import device
from keystate_manager import KeyboardInputManager
from directinput_constants import DIK_UP, DIK_DOWN, DIK_LEFT, DIK_RIGHT, DIK_NUMLOCK, DIK_SPACE
from win32con import VK_NUMLOCK
from win32api import GetKeyState
except:
    logger.exception("EXCEPTION FROM IMPORTS")

class RuneDetector:
    def __init__(self, model_path, labels=None, screen_capturer=None, key_mgr=None):
    """
    Run just Once to initialize
    :param model_path: Path to trained keras model
    :param labels: dictionary with class names as keys, integer as values
    example: {'down': 0, 'left': 1, 'right': 2, 'up': 3}
    """
    self.logger = logging.getLogger("RuneDetector")
    self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    fh = logging.FileHandler("logging.log")
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    self.logger.addHandler(fh)
    self.labels = labels if labels else {'down': 0, 'left': 1, 'right': 2, 'up': 3}
    self.model_path = model_path
    with device("/cpu:0"):  # Use cpu for evaluation
        model = load_model(self.model_path)
        #model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.load_weights(self.model_path)

    self.model = model

    self.rune_roi_1366 = [450, 180, 500, 130]  # x, y, w, h
    self.rune_roi_1024 = [295, 180, 500, 133]
    self.rune_roi_800 = [170,200, 440, 135]
    self.rune_roi = self.rune_roi_800  # set as default rune roi
    self.screen_processor = IMGScreenCapturer() if not screen_capturer else screen_capturer
    self.key_mgr = KeyboardInputManager() if not key_mgr else key_mgr

def capture_roi(self):
    screen_rect = self.screen_processor.ms_get_screen_rect(self.screen_processor.ms_get_screen_hwnd())
    screen_width = screen_rect[2]-screen_rect[0]

    if screen_width > 1300:
        self.rune_roi = self.rune_roi_1366
    elif screen_width > 1000:
        self.rune_roi = self.rune_roi_1024
    elif screen_width > 800:
        self.rune_roi = self.rune_roi_800

    captured_image = self.screen_processor.capture(set_focus=False, rect=screen_rect)

    captured_roi = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(captured_image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    captured_roi = captured_roi[self.rune_roi[1]:self.rune_roi[1]+self.rune_roi[3], self.rune_roi[0]:self.rune_roi[0]+self.rune_roi[2]]

    return captured_roi

def preprocess(self, img):
    """
    finds and returns sorted list of 60 by 60 grayscale images of circles, centered
    :param img: BGR image of roi containing circle
    :return: list of grayscale images each containing a circle
    """
    hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    hsv_img[:, :, 1] = 255
    hsv_img[:, :, 2] = 255
    bgr_img = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray_img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, gray_img.shape[0] / 8, param1=100, param2=30, minRadius=18, maxRadius=30)
    temp_list = []
    img_index = 1
    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
        for (x, y, r) in circles:

            cropped = gray_img[max(0, int(y - 60 / 2)):int(y + 60 / 2), max(0, int(x - 60 / 2)):int(x + 60 / 2)].astype(np.float32)

            temp_list.append((cropped, (x, y)))
            img_index += 1

    temp_list = sorted(temp_list, key= lambda x: x[1][0])
    return_list = []
    for image in temp_list:
        return_list.append(image[0])

    return return_list

def images2tensor(self, img_list):
    """
    Creates a tf compliant tensor by stacking images in img_list
    :param img_list:
    :return: np.array of shape [1, 60, 60, 1]
    """
    return np.vstack([np.reshape(x, [1, 60, 60, 1]) for x in img_list])

def classify(self, tensor, batch_size = 4):
    """
    Runs tensor through model and returns list of direction in string.
    :param tensor: input tensor
    :param batch_size: batch size
    :return: size of strings "up", "down", "left", "right"
    """
    return_list = []
    result = self.model.predict(tensor, batch_size=batch_size)
    for res in result:
        final_class = np.argmax(res, axis=-1)
        for key, val in self.labels.items():
            if final_class == val:
                return_list.append(key)

    return return_list

def solve_auto(self):
    """
    Solves rune if present and sends key presses.
    :return: -1 if rune not detected, result of classify() if successful
    """
    img = self.capture_roi()
    processed_imgs = self.preprocess(img)
    if len(processed_imgs) != 4:
        return -1
    #cv2.imwrite("roi.png", img)
    tensor = self.images2tensor(processed_imgs)
    result = self.classify(tensor)
    if GetKeyState(VK_NUMLOCK):
        self.key_mgr.single_press(DIK_NUMLOCK)
        time.sleep(0.2)
    self.logger.debug("Solved rune with solution %s"%(str(result)))
    for inp in result:
        if inp == "up":
            self.key_mgr.single_press(DIK_UP)
        elif inp == "down":
            self.key_mgr.single_press(DIK_DOWN)
        elif inp == "left":
            self.key_mgr.single_press(DIK_LEFT)
        elif inp == "right":
            self.key_mgr.single_press(DIK_RIGHT)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    return len(processed_imgs)

def press_space(self):
    self.key_mgr.single_press(DIK_SPACE)

def solve(self):
    """
    Solves rune if present and just returns solution.
    :return: -1 if rune not detected, result of classify() if successful
    """
    img = self.capture_roi()
    processed_imgs = self.preprocess(img)
    if len(processed_imgs) != 4:
        return -1
    tensor = self.images2tensor(processed_imgs)
    result = self.classify(tensor)

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
try:
    label = {'down': 0, 'left': 1, 'right': 2, 'up': 3}

    solver = RuneDetector("arrow_classifier_keras_gray.h5", label)
    logger.debug("Log start")
    logger.debug("screen handle: " + str(solver.screen_processor.ms_get_screen_hwnd()))
    logger.debug("screen rect: " + str(solver.screen_processor.ms_get_screen_rect(solver.screen_processor.ms_get_screen_hwnd())))
    # solver.scrp.screen_capture(800,600, save=True, save_name="dta.png")
    logger.debug("Start processing input...")
    while True:
        img = solver.capture_roi()
        cv2.imshow("ExIt: Q", img)

        return_val = solver.solve_auto()
        if return_val == -1:
            print("no rune detected")
        else:
            logger.debug("Finished solving runes.")
        k = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if k == ord("q"):
            break
    logger.debug("Application exit.")
except:
    logger.exception("EXCEPTION")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us the script?

Comment: What is the code that you are using? Can you share this in your question?

Comment: 3480 elements are, in general, insufficient to populate an array of 60 * 60 = 3600 elements. Is the size of your array conditional on some other program flow?

Comment: I upload the code @nopassport1

Comment: I upload the code @RenatevanKempen